# Android Layout: How to align with respect to rightmost view but keep all elements left aligned

Tags: android, android-layout

```
[short text][image1][image2]____________________________________

[this is a reallyyyyyyy.............y long text][image1][image2]
```

I have 3 views: one TextView of variable size and two small images (16dp x 16dp) and want to achieve a layout such that images are always shown as 16dp x 16dp and text should be shown in leftover space and ellipsized if too long. The group of 3 views should be all left aligned and be next to each other.

**Approaches tried:**

1. LinearLayout with no weights

   Drawback: When TextView is large, ImageViews are not shown.
2. LinearLayout with weights

   Drawback: ImageViews are no longer adjacent to each other but take up space in ratio of weights.
3. RelativeLayout - image2: alignParentBottom, image1: toLeftOf="image2", text: toLeftOf="image1"

   Drawback: All the elements now are right aligned.

   ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**[short text][image1][image2]

How can such a layout be achieved? Preferably without nesting?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: I think this is a similar question, if not exactly the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32593845/android-layout-how-to-keep-right-most-text-element-and-ellipsize-left-most-text

Comment: I received an answer to my question there. I tried the suggested answer and it checks out.

Answer (score 1):

You should use your third aproach but set the textview gravity to left.

Something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want to keep the textview in only one line use `android:singleLine="true"`

Comment: That makes it appear as [short text]____________________[image1][image2], whereas expected is [short text][image1][image2]. ___ represents whitespace here.

Comment: Well then i think i didn't understand what you wanted... :/

Comment: That would be same as approach #3 I had tried. With or without gravity="right" does the same thing. Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 0):

## This trick worked for me. Try this if this can help you.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingRight="32dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="This is a very large text just to test the alignment of the images with the textview" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="16dp"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="16dp"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```