# Android Layout: How to keep right-most text element and ellipsize left-most text element as it grows?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout which contains two TextViews. Let the first TextView's text be "short text" and the 2nd TextView's text be "(s)".

```xml
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/variable-size"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="middle"
            android:lines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="short text"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fixed-size"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:lines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="(s)" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want the LinearLayout to appear to the user thus:

`[[short text][(s)]____________]`

where `____` means empty view.

Now if I put a slightly longer string into the first TextView, I want to see this:

`[[slightly longer text][(s)]__]`

and if I put a much longer string into the first TextView, I want to see this:

`[[really long ...ng text][(s)]]`

But I can't seem to find a way to keep the first TextView from crowding out the second TextView altogether, like so:

`[[really long lo... long text]]`

How do I get the behavior I am looking for?

Comment: Any reason to not use only one text view and append the "s" to the end?

Comment: I want the end of the "long text" string to be visible when ellipsized. If I put the "(s)" in there I lose that.

Comment: I do not know if is there a way to achive this only by xml. But I'm sure it is possible to call `setMaxWidth` into your `variable_size` text view programmatically and get the results you are expecting.

Comment: @tato.rodrigo Yeah, that seems like a decent approach - make a custom view, overload the `onMeasure()` to get the size of the `fixed_size` view, use that to compute the maximum size of the `variable_size` view, which we set in an overloaded `onLayout()`, and otherwise let LinearLayout do its thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The base of the answer to your question is this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/variable-size"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:lines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="short text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fixed-size"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:lines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="(s)" />

</LinearLayout>
```

***BUT...*** bare in mind that I changed the width of your `LinearLayout` from:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

and that's a really important part of the answer.

The code I presented works like this:

```
[[short text][(s)]]
[[slightly longer text][(s)]]
[[really long ...ng text][(s)]]
```

It manages the ellipsizing correctly, but cannot introduce the "empty view" (`____`). If I didn't change the `LinearLayout's` `layout_width`, the ellipsizing would work correctly (`(s)` wouldn't be pushed off the screen), but the text alignment wouldn`t be correct. It would look like this:

```
[[short text            ][(s)]]
[[slightly longer text  ][(s)]]
[[really long ...ng text][(s)]]
```

So if the "empty view" is a need for you, you will need to implement it (for example) with nesting your `LinearLayout` inside another one (and this time "empty view" is gonna be an actual `View`). Like so:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/variable-size"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="middle"
            android:lines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="short text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fixed-size"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:lines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="(s)" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This will give you the following behaviour:

```
[[[short text][(s)]]____________]
[[[slightly longer text][(s)]]__]
[[[really long ...ng text][(s)]]]
```